# FirebaseListAdapter displaying wrong data on scrolling

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using FirebaseListAdapter to populate ListView. It is working fine for the data populated directly from Firebase. Here, I am trying to display/hide a tick image based on the status field. On initial load it is working fine, but when I scroll up and down the tick mark is getting set for some of the other items incorrectly. Need help! Here is my code inside populateView.

```
nameTextView.setText(appointment.getName());
timeTextView.setText(appointment.getTime());

if (appointment.getAppointmentStatus() == APPOINTMENT_COMPLETED) {
    appStatusImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
} else {
    appStatusImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: @Selvin Not sure why it is down voted. I know view reusing is happening here. Even after adding else part it is not working. What is missing here? Appreciate if you share the solution.

Comment: obviously `else` should contain "opposite action" ... `setVisibility` is not "opposite" to `setImageResource` now code is even worst ... and downvote is obvious, too ... you didn't even tried to find similar question here

Comment: @Selvin if this question has been asked before, please take a moment to find a duplicate and close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens probably because you are using a `RecyclerView`, that meaning that the `Views` are reused instead of each object having it's own View. In other words, when you write:

```
if (appointment.getAppointmentStatus() == APPOINTMENT_COMPLETED) {
    appStatusImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
}
```

Initially, you will set your View with the given image if it meets your `if` statement. But if the `View` itself is reused for another object that does not meet the `if` statement, the image resource will remain from the previous object property. What you should do is:

```
if (appointment.getAppointmentStatus() == APPOINTMENT_COMPLETED) {
    appStatusImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
    appStatusImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    appStatusImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

And everything should work as you expect

Comment: I added the else part as suggested. But still the first item is not retaining its state after scrolling up and down. I am using FirebaseListAdapter. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Check my edited post. If you set the image to be invisible, once reused you will also need to set it back to visible

Comment: It is working fine now. Thanks for answering patiently and helping me out. Appreciate it.